# Remove spaces from a single column using bash

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

I was provided with a CSV file, that in a single column, uses spaces to denote a thousands separator (eg. 11 000 instead of 11,000 or 11000). The other columns have useful spaces within them, so I need to only fix this one column.

My data:

```
Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11 000.90
```

I need to get:

```
Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11000.90
```

I have been trying awk, sed, and cut, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

dirty and quick:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub(/ /,"",$NF)}1'
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11 000.90"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{gsub(/ /,"",$NF)}1'
Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11000.90
```

Comment: just for further information, `$NF` can be replaced with `$n` to make the change in any `nth` column specific

Comment: Awesome, worked perfectly, thank you Kent! I'm going to search around to see how this actually works, but if you wouldn't mind explaining it to me, I'd be grateful.

Comment: The options tell `awk` to use comma as the field separator for both input (`-F,`) and output (`-v OFS=,`).  `gsub(/ /,"",somestring)` replaces spaces (that's a space between the `/`...`/`) with nothing at all (`""`) in the given string. NF is the number of (comma-delimited, thanks to `-F,`) fields, and `$`n is the nth field , so `$NF` means the last field on the line.  The `1` at the end tells awk to do its default thing afterward, which is to print the modified fields back out, separated by OFS. So: delete all spaces in the last comma-separated field of each line.

Comment: also, since that looks golfish, I'll note that you don't actually need the quotes in `-v OFS=,`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) \([0-9]\)/\1\2/'
```

This looks for two digits either side of a blank and keeps just the two digits.  For the data shown, it would work fine.  You can add a trailing `g` if you might have to deal with `11 234 567.89`.

If you might have other columns with spaces between numbers, or not the first such column, you can use a similar technique/regex in `awk` with `gsub()` on the relevant field.

Answer (score 0):

just with bash

```
$ echo "Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11 000.90" |
while IFS=, read -r date source amount; do
    echo "$date,$source,${amount// /}"
done
```

```
Date,Source,Amount
1/1/2013,Ben's Chili Bowl,11000.90
```