# Replace in a CSV file value of a column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, sed, awk

I have a a CSV file with this structure:

```
31126000283424431;32285076389;t;text text;1;3;;1;1;0.9;0.81;0;0;1;1;1;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000279521531;32308233749;c;text text;1;2;;1;9;2.79;7.78;0;0;4;16;9;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000279406931;32291254349;c;text text;1;5;;1;3;0.98;0.96;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000272138431;32284912829;c;text text;1;3;;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000271468431;32304086789;t;text text;1;5;;1;1;0.2;0.04;0;0;2;4;1;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000269838731;29269530509;c;text text;1;1;;1;1;0.45;0.2;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
```

and I need to replace the number after the sixth semicolon to 0.

So the output file would look like:

```
31126000283424431;32285076389;t;text text;1;0;;1;1;0.9;0.81;0;0;1;1;1;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000279521531;32308233749;c;text text;1;0;;1;9;2.79;7.78;0;0;4;16;9;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000279406931;32291254349;c;text text;1;0;;1;3;0.98;0.96;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000272138431;32284912829;c;text text;1;0;;1;1;0;0;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000271468431;32304086789;t;text text;1;0;;1;1;0.2;0.04;0;0;2;4;1;2013-11-21;;NL
31126000269838731;29269530509;c;text text;1;0;;1;1;0.45;0.2;0;0;3;9;0;2013-11-21;;NL
```

I have been trying awk, sed, and cut, but I can't get it to work.

thank you

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @pfnuesel Valid point.  However, it's only a matter when answers start to roll in.

Comment: I tried things from this two post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487395/remove-spaces-from-a-single-column-using-bash
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492590/using-bash-sed-awk-to-extract-rows-and-columns-in-csv-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your example shows the 6th col, but after the **5th** semi.

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '$6=0;7' file
```

try the line above

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/;[^;]\{1,\}/;0/5" YourFile.csv
```

assume there is always something in colum

```
sed "s/;[^;]*/;0/5" YourFile.csv
```

change in every case even if there is no number is 6th column

Answer (score 0):

If you've got php on your machine you could use this very handy [CSV Paser class](https://code.google.com/p/php-csv-parser/). It will convert your CSV in to a 2D array, from which you can cycle through using a foreach loop and change the data.

```
$csvFile
foreach($csvFile as $value){
    foreach($value as $k => $v){
        if($k == 5){ $v = 0}
    }
}
```

This would automate it for a CSV file of any size of the same format.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -e'$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new({sep_char=>";", eol=>"\n"}); while($row=$csv->getline(ARGV)) {$row->[5]=0;$csv->print(STDOUT, $row)}'
```

Use as filter or put input file as parameter. You should use proper CSV parser for any serious work.