# Replacing dynamically changing regular expressions using sed

Tags: shell, sed

```
,"some values1","some values2",Not Processed,0,
```

Is there any way I could replace the above pattern, irrespective of whatever values come in some values1 or some values2 with the lines below,

```
,,,Not Processed,0,
```

This string is just a part of a large file I have.

Comment: please try to be more clear .. what you want to replace and with what .... we will definatly try to help you

Comment: @PuneetSinha I want to replace with empty values as I mentioned in the desired O/P,

Comment: How about Perl? `perl -i.bak -wple 's!^,"[^"]+","[^]",!,"","",!' file.csv`

Comment: @Corion could you please tell me how to do that in sed, also the  lines I mentioned in the question are a part of a larger string, in one line the first value might be in 5th position and in the next line it may vary . Only the pattern which I mentioned in the question remains unchanged.

Comment: ... sorry (too late to edit) `How about Perl? `perl -i.bak -wple 's!^,"[^"]+","[^"]",!,"","",!' file.csv``

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and write there what the constant pattern is and what the variable pattern is. From what you've shown, it is completely unclear where the pattern starts and ends.

Comment: Maybe try `perl -i.bak -wple 's!,"[^"]*","[^"]*",Not Processed,0!,"","",Not Processed,0,!'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425763/replace-in-a-csv-file-value-of-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem I believe:

```sh
test_data() {
  cat <<EOF
  ,"val1,val2...","val1,val2,val3..",Not Processed,0,
  ,"val1,val2..","",Not Processed,0,
  ,"","val1,val2,val3....",Not Processed,0,
EOF
}

test_data | sed -e 's/\(.*\),"[^"]*","[^"]*",\(Not Processed,0,\)\(.*\)/\1,,,\2\3/g'
```

Output:

```
▶ bash data.sh
  ,,,Not Processed,0,
  ,,,Not Processed,0,
  ,,,Not Processed,0,
```

Comment: This is highly speculative. With the samples the OP supplied, simply replacing every string with `,"","",Not Processed,0,` would fulfill their requirements.

Comment: Yes I see your point. I’ll wait until the question is clarified.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I have edited the question,Could you please check that

Comment: If your question is correct now, then this answer is correct, too. Does it not work for you?

Comment: It works now, thanks